# Errors in visual studio code after requireing the mongodb api mongoose in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I'm learning basic web development and I got started with databases using MongoDB atlas and mongoose.

I usually use the node.js(legacy) debugger in VS code to debug my code because of the great profiling options but for some reason when I use it after I've done `` const mongoose = require(`mongoose`) `` in my code it gives me errors within multiple node modules, but when I use PowerShell and `node .\app.js` it works without giving me the errors.

If anyone knows why this is happening and how to stop it, it would be greatly appreciated if you could help me.

[image: this image shows the error in what I hope is full detail]

I know that requireing the mongoose module causes this because I've tried it without the module required and it worked fine.

If more data and more detailed descriptions are required I will gladly edit them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run something like this with the built in Vscode debugger you have to just run it and not debug it.

The default key bind for just running it is: `ctr + F5`